# TypeScript issues with CSV upload and nginx

Tags: javascript, typescript, csv, nginx, flask

I am trying to upload a csv file to my backend filled with binance data.

Here is the .tsx:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import Context from "./Context";

const BinanceCSVUpload = ({ handleClose }: { handleClose: any }) => {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(Context);
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [formErrorState, setFormErrorState] = useState("");

  const handleFileChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!file) {
      alert("Please select a CSV file to upload.");
      return;
    }

    console.log(file);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    // Log the contents of formData
    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      console.log(key, value);
    });

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "/api/accounts/csv_upload",
        {
          // Adjust URL if needed
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        const text = await response.text(); // Read the response body
        console.error("Upload failed:", response.statusText, text);
        setFormErrorState("SUBMIT_FAILED");
        return;
      }
      const data = await response.text();
      alert(data);

      dispatch({
        type: "SET_STATE",
        state: {
          refreshBinanceCSV: true,
        },
      });

      if (handleClose) {
        handleClose();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert("An error occurred: " + error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
      <label>
        Upload Binance CSV File:
        <input
          type="file"
          name="file"
          accept=".csv"
          onChange={handleFileChange}
          required
        />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default BinanceCSVUpload;
```

This is calling this flask endpoint:

```
@app.route("/accounts/csv_upload", methods=["POST"])
```

However, it seems to be getting intercepted calling 500 internal server error as I'm receiving this error on the frontend:

`POST http://localhost/api/accounts/csv_upload 500 (Internal Server Error)`

My nginx.conf file should be accepting it, which is seen here:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      '' close;
  }

  upstream grafana {
       server localhost:3000;
  }

server {
  
    
  listen 80;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;
  
  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_read_timeout 300s;
      client_max_body_size 100M;
      proxy_buffering off;
  }
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_read_timeout 300s;
      client_max_body_size 100M;
      proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

The error code popup is flashing the nginx version, coupled with 500 internal server error, and I am not getting any logs in the backend, so I assume this is a frontend / nginx issue.

Thank you.

Comment: 500 error usually happens when the request hits the correct endpoint and the error happens inside your backend code.

Comment: @technophyle The issue is that I have a print statement that should be hit first before anything else, and it's not getting pinged. I'm not quite sure what the error is. 

When I remove the `body: formData` from the code, it hits the backend but gives me this error: 

`"POST /accounts/crypto/accounting/binance/csv_upload HTTP/1.0" 500 -
An error occurred: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`